# FrameLayout & AbsoluteLayout gives error When I used In the same XML file?

Tags: android, android-framelayout, absolutelayout

**This is structure what I'm using**

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <AbsoluteLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/abs_layout">
            <ImageView    />
            <ImageView   />
    </AbsoluteLayout>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Above Structure  work fine but when I used below structure gives error**

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

    <AbsoluteLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/abs_layout">
            <ImageView    />
            <ImageView   />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Error Log:**

```
10-14 10:35:54.134: E/AndroidRuntime(13044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 10:35:54.134: E/AndroidRuntime(13044): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.d/com.example.d.DMainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsoluteLayout
10-14 10:35:54.134: E/AndroidRuntime(13044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-14 10:35:54.134: E/AndroidRuntime(13044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
```

Comment: Absolute layout is deprecated from a long time.Use some other layout to achieve your requirement

Comment: can you shown hows ur layout look like graphically then try to achieve this by some other way ?

Comment: @Haresh : Still I m just sort out this thing.. other way is this last option  but i want to understand this problem first . hope you can understand

Comment: I want to use drag and drop functionality in ABSLayout. I tried drag and drop in other layout but it not giving the o/p what I need @BirajZalavadia

Comment: Code seems fine,Clean rebuild your project, if problem still persists delete R.java and rebuild again.

Comment: Can you please tell me the reason about this ... @Brontok

Comment: There is a problem with Eclipse i.e. re-creating views, Some time there occurs problem in R.java as it has already defined a view in it. So it won't recognize whether a view is changed from say AbsoluteLayout to ImageView, It still thinks its still the same view. That is why clean and re-build works and the final solution is delete your R.java files so that it may create reference of views again.